# Lost my passport which had valid Canadian visa

Tags: canada, lost-documents

I have recently lost my Pakistani Passport in Pakistan which had a valid Canadian Multiple Visit visa which was valid for another 5 years. I have traveled once on the lost passport. I have filed a police report and got the new Pakistani Passport issued. Can someone please guide me what to do now to get the Canada visit visa sticker on the new passport? 
Thanks and best regards,
Sakina

Answer (score 8):

Canada calls its visitor visas "Temporary Resident Visas";  the sticker which goes in your passport is called a "counterfoil".  A lost temporary resident counterfoil [can be replaced](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=044&top=12) from outside Canada:

> #### Outside Canada
>
> You may have the following current, valid immigration documents replaced:
>
> - temporary resident visa counterfoil;
> - permanent resident visa counterfoil;
> - confirmation of permanent residence;

The form for requesting a replacement is the [Application for a Verification of Status (VOS) or Replacement of an Immigration Document.](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/application-verification-status-replacement-immigration-document.html)  The appropriate forms and instructions are available at that link.  You'll need a photocopy of your passport (ideally your old one if you have it, your new one if not), a photocopy of your birth certificate, and the number of the police report.  All documents must be translated into English or French if they are not already in one of those languages.